# How to specify which OData version to return from a WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to specify which DataServiceVersion to return from my WCF Data Service? As it is now even if I specify V2 by using

```
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
```

calls to the service still returns DataServiceVersion: 1.0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server will return the lowest possible version for the given response. So if the response contains only V1 features, then it will be V1.

The client can override this by sending the MinDataServiceVersion header in which case the server will send the response of the version at least that high. This was only implemented in WCF DS 5.0 and higher though.

Comment: The server works this way so that downlevel clients (V1 clients) keep working. If you really don't want to support downlevel clients, you can override OnStartProcessingRequest method on DataService class, and throw if the MaxDataServiceVersion header is specified and its value is less than 2.0. Hope this helps.